# How to map a column in data frame using pyhton

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnmappings, csv-header

I need to map a column names in data frame using python, I have some different data set in my csv need to match (mapping) a columns to standard name like following .

set 1                                                      set 2

userId :[(1,2,3)]                                          customerId : [(1,2,3)]
userName :[('sam','ram','mam')]                            customerName : [('raj','tej','tej')]
contact : [('sam@gmail','ram@gmail','mam@gmail')]          email : [('raj@gmail','tej@gmail','tej@gmail')]

I need like

pd[id]=pd[userId] or pd[customerId]
pd[name]=pd[userName ] or pd[customerName]

I have tried or condition using pandas . its working but I needd some standard solution.

```
if 'Number' in df.columns:
    df_new = df.rename(columns = {'Number': 'Id'})
    if 'Address' in df.columns:
    df_new = df.rename(columns = {'Address': 'address'})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mapper = {'Number': 'Id', 'Address': 'address'}
# If 'ignore', existing keys will be renamed and extra keys will be ignored.
df.rename(columns=mapper, errors='ignore')
```